# Detect new line c++ fstream

Tags: c++, fstream, file-io

How do I read a .txt copy the content to another .txt by using fstream to a similar content.
The problem is, when in the file there is new line. How do I detect that while using ifstream?

user enter "apple"

Eg:
note.txt =>
I bought an apple yesterday.
The apple tastes delicious.

note_new.txt => 
I bought an yesterday. 
tastes delicious.

the resulting note suppose to be above, but instead:
note_new.txt => 
I bought an yesterday. tastes delicious.

How do I check if there is a new line in the source file, it also will create new line in new file.

Here is my current code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string> 

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream inFile ("note.txt");
    string word;
    ofstream outFile("note_new.txt");

    while(inFile >> word) {
        outfile << word << " ";
    }
}
```

can you all help me? actually I also check when the word retrieved is the same as what user specified, then I won't write that word in the new file. So it general, it will delete words which are the same as the one specified by user.

Comment: hint: `std::getline()`

Comment: Is there a reason you're parsing the file word by word?  The easiest way to get the identical file is to not parse at all and just read/write binary data or use whatever platform specific api is available to just copy the file.

Comment: @RetiredNinja actually I also check when the word retrieved is the same as what user specified, then I won't write that word in the new file. So it general, it will delete words which are the same as the one specified by user.

Comment: You should specify that in your question as it doesn't fit the "exactly the same content" part.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Line-by-line method

If you still want to do it line-by-line, you can use [`std::getline()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string> 

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream inFile ("note.txt");
    string line;
    //     ^^^^
    ofstream outFile("note_new.txt");

    while( getline(inFile, line) ) {
    //     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        outfile << line << endl;
    }
}
```

It gets a line from the stream and you just to rewrite it wherever you want.

---

#### Easier method

If you just want to rewrite one file inside the other one, use [`rdbuf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/rdbuf/) :

```
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream inFile ("note.txt");
    ofstream outFile("note_new.txt");

    outFile << inFile.rdbuf();
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

---

**EDIT :** It will permit to remove the words you don't want to be in the new file :

We use [`std::stringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/) :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string> 

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream inFile ("note.txt");
    string line;
    string wordEntered("apple"); // Get it from the command line
    ofstream outFile("note_new.txt");

    while( getline(inFile, line) ) {
        
        stringstream ls( line );
        string word;

        while(ls >> word)
        {
            if (word != wordEntered)
            {
                 outFile << word;
            }
        }
        outFile << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a much easier way to do the job:

```
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    std::ifstream inFile ("note.txt");
    std::ofstream outFile("note_new.txt");

    outFile << inFile.rdbuf();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove text from the input file (as your description suggests but does not state).

Then you need to read line by line. But then each line needs to be parsed word by word to make sure you can remove the work you are looking for `apple`.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string> 

using namespace std;
// Don't do this. 

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argv == 1) { std::cerr << "Usage: Need a word to remove\n";exit(1);}
    std::string userWord = argv[1];  // Get user input (from command line)

    std::ifstream inFile("note.txt");
    std::ofstream outFile("note_new.txt");
    std::string   line;

    while(std::getline(inFile, line))
    {
         // Got a line
         std::stringstream linestream(line);
         std::string  word;

         while(linestream >> word)
         {
                // Got a word from the line.
                if (word != userWord)
                {
                     outFile << word;
                }
         }
         // After you have processed each line.
         // Add a new line to the output.
         outFile << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably want to add spaces between the words, most likely before writing each token after the first on each line to prevent a trailing space at the end of the line.  Even then it wouldn't preserve any extra whitespace in the file if that is important.

Comment: @RetiredNinja: Indeed. Also need to compensate for punctuation. But I can't do everything.