# Test set for reflexive, symmetric, or transitive using a struct

Tags: c++

I have this struct in my code

```
struct Pair
{
  int x,y;
  friend bool operator==(Pair a, Pair b)
  {
     return a.x == b.x && a.y == b.y;
  }
  friend istream& operator>>(istream& is, Pair& a)
  {
    is >> a.x >> a.y;
    return is;
 }
 friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Pair a)
 {
    os << '(' << a.x << ',' << a.y << ')';
    return os;
 }
};

int main(){
Pair p;
fstream file;
string fileName = "Text.txt";
file.open(fileName.c_str(), fstream::in);
if(!file){
    cout << "Could Not Open " << fileName << " File" << endl;
}else{
    int size = 43;
    int * myArray = new int[size];
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        file >> myArray[i];
    }
    printArray(myArray,size);
}
return 0;
```

}

Reading From A text File

> 5 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5
>
> 7 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 4 7 7 4 7 7
>
> 8 1 1 2 4 3 9 4 16 5 25 6 36 7 49 8 64

This file has 3 relations in it, each one starts with an int which is the number of pairs in that relation, then that many pairs follows. Then (if not eof) read another int and that many pairs again, and so on.

How can I read this data into my struct pair?

Comment: Can you post the code that does the reading?

Comment: @JosephSible yes, I will put what I have so far. I just can't seem to find a way to incorporate the struct

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/18324410/2483065

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More or less something like this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <vector>

struct Pair
{
    int x,y;
    friend bool operator==(Pair a, Pair b)
    {
        return a.x == b.x && a.y == b.y;
    }
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Pair& a)
    {
        is >> a.x >> a.y;
        return is;
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Pair a)
    {
        os << '(' << a.x << ',' << a.y << ')';
        return os;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::fstream file;
    file.open("Text.txt", std::fstream::in);

    std::list<std::vector<Pair> > relations;
    int size = 0;
    while(file >> size)
    {
        relations.emplace_back(size);
        for(int i=0; i < relations.back().size() && file >> relations.back()[i]; i++);
    }

    //Print
    for(auto &r : relations)
    {
        std::cout << "[";
        for(auto &p : r)
        {
            std::cout << p;
        }
        std::cout << "]\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/viewproject.php?URL=compile_cpp11_online.php&PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMbUdzUjc0bWlqb3M)